# Understanding 手を取り

Tags: verbs, expressions

So I'm trying to understand the expression 手を取り (to take hands) in the context of this lyric from "Suteki Da Ne":

> 二人手をとり 歩けたなら

I know that since 取り is 取る's stem form, it can act like the te-form 取って. As the lyric involves two people, that make the lyric something like "If the two of us could take hands and walk." However, 取り合う (to take each other by the hand) or "hand in hand" would be more grammatically correct, but change the lyric.

Comment: Try searching both 手を取り and 取り合う on jpdb.io and see some example sentences.
Maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it is to match the melody. I have the impression that only one person is trying to take the other's hand, but it is not so strange.

Answer (score 1):

The masu stem form of a verb is commonly used to connect multiple verbs together and indicate the sequence of actions or events. It doesn’t directly translate to “and” but rather implies that one action follows another.

In the sentence 手を取り歩ける　the masu stem form of 取る　(which is 取り) is used to connect the 2 verbs - hold hands and walk. The sentence 二人手をとり 歩けたなら would translate to “if only the two of us could take hands and (then) walk.”